# Non-static method calling inside a class is not Deprecated in PHP?

Tags: php

As PHP manual stated

> As of PHP 7.0.0 calling a non-static method statically has been
>   generally deprecated (even if called from a compatible context).

To check this statement-

I am calling a Non-static method outside a class then its generating error

```
class A{
    public function foo(){
        echo "testing<br/>";
    }
}
A::foo();
```

> Deprecated: Non-static method A::foo() should not be called statically

But when I am calling a Non-static method inside a class then its not generating `Deprecated error`

```
class A{
    public function foo(){
        echo "testing<br/>";
    }

    public function Display(){
        A::foo();    //calling a Non-static method inside statically
        self::foo(); //calling a Non-static method inside statically
    }
}
$obj=new A();
$obj->Display();
```

Does it deprecated only when calling statically from outside the class?

Comment: Try from a static method.

Comment: inside class you can all data or method using class name there is no need to define static data or method but outside the class yous can not use data and method using class name if its not define with static keword, you can access with class object

Answer (score 5):

The Scope Resolution operator, or the double colon operator, isn't just used for static calls.

Inside a class the operator can be used to reference the class itself in a non-static way.

This is what you have done for self::foo() and A::foo(); 
 To make a static call inside the class you need to use the `static::<methodName>` statement

Take a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php

Answer (score 1):

Using `A::` or `self::` inside class methods, refers as `$this->`. From [Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

> **Warning** In PHP 7, calling non-static methods statically is deprecated,
>   and will generate an E_DEPRECATED warning. Support for calling
>   non-static methods statically may be removed in the future.